# Как обновить формы без пересборки проекта Django?

Tags: python, django

У меня есть проект на django, я внес изменения в атрибуты одного текстового поля:

```
from django import forms

class ContactForm(forms.Form):
    name = forms.CharField(label="Имя:", required=True, max_length=50, widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'size':40,'class': 'form-control'}))
    phone = forms.CharField(label="Номер:", required=True, max_length=20, widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'size':40,'class': 'form-control'}))
    website = forms.CharField(label="Сайт:", max_length=50, widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'size':40,'class': 'form-control'}))
    message = forms.CharField(label="Техническое задание или другой комментарий:", widget=forms.Textarea(attrs={'size':200, 'rows':6, 'class': 'form-control'}))
```

Но изменения на сайте нет. Как мне без пересборки проекта обновить эту форму?

Comment: Что такое «пересборка проекта»?

Comment: В общем, я некорректно выражаюсь, но насколько я понимаю, определение класса формы происходит один раз - при её загрузке. И как мне переопределить этот класс?

Comment: Просто перезапустить Django, чтобы все классы определились заново?

Comment: Как мне правильно это сделать? Просто у меня проект на vps стоит, и использует gunicorn и nginx

Comment: Вот gunicorn и перезапустите, наверное?

Comment: Все, разобрался. Спасибо